# Radio Set CSS Styling, stack some buttons but not others

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to stack some radio buttons while leaving another on it's own because it has additional content.

My fiddle is here
http://jsfiddle.net/CkRF4/5/

```
<p>Style Radio Set</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CkRF4/6/) will give you a start.

Just a big div with a series of floated divs. Then three divs stacked inside.

I'm sure there are more elegant ways, just can't think of anything this late.

HTML (one floated div)

```
<div class='holder'>
  <div class='littleholder'>
    <input type='radio' id='scores' name='scores1' />
    <label for='scores'>Assign All Scores</label>
  </div>
  <div class='littleholder'>
    &nbsp;To:&nbsp;<input type='text' />&nbsp;out of 1
  </div>
  <div class='littleholder'>
    <input type='checkbox'/>Overwrite Scores
  </div>
</div>
```